# Dual Hopper Grinder, Single Brewer, Mixing Flavors! Please help!

Tags: flavored-coffee, brewing-process, coffee-shop

I own a small coffee shop, and the regulars love their flavored coffee.  To help improve the workflow, I bought a dual hopper grinder.  One side is flavored, the other is regular/house.  We brew both in the same brewer, but into different pots and with different baskets, but I still get the taste of flavored in my regular.

In an attempt to try and prevent this, I've programmed one switch on my grinder to "purge" the flavored.  It runs a quick 1-2 second purge using regular beans through the grinder and into the flavored basket.

Has anyone dealt with this issue or does anyone know how to prevent them from mixing short of separate grinders and brewers?

Comment: What do you mean with _flavored coffee_?